# Python Pathlib escaping string stored in variable

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm on **windows** and have an api response that includes a key value pair like

```
object = {'path':'/my_directory/my_subdirectory/file.txt'}
```

I'm trying to use pathlib to open and create that structure relative to the current working directory as well as a user supplied directory name in the current working directory like this:

```py
output = "output_location"
path = pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath(output,object['path'])
print(path)
```

What this gives me is this

> c:\directory\my_subdirectory\file.txt

Whereas I'm looking for it to output something like:

> **'c:\current_working_directory\output_location\directory\my_subdirectory\file.txt'**

The issue is because the object['path'] is a variable I'm not sure how to escape it as a raw string. And so I think the escapes are breaking it. I can't guarantee there will always be a leading slash in the object['path'] value so I don't want to simply trim the first character.

I was hoping there was an elegant way to do this using pathlib that didn't involve ugly string manipulation.

Comment: That is not a "key-value pair", which implies a dictionary of sorts. That is a `set` object. So which is it?

Comment: it is a key-value I just didn't add any of the other key values. its an api response in json->dict format

Comment: `object = {'path','/my_directory/my_subdirectory/file.txt'}` is a set notice the comma. `object = {'path':'/my_directory/my_subdirectory/file.txt'}` is a dictionary, notice the colon ':'.

Comment: sorry,f. Yeah typo. fixed

Comment: Hope my answer provides the needed results. Provide comments if not :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `lstrip('/')`

You want to remove your leading slash whenever it’s there, because pathlib will ignore whatever comes before it.

Comment: yeah I haven't found a more elegant solution than this

Answer (score 0):

```
import pathlib

object = {'path': '/my_directory/my_subdirectory/file.txt'}
output = "output_location"
# object['path'][1:] removes the initial '/'
path = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(pathlib.Path.cwd()).joinpath(output,object[
    'path'][1:])
# path = pathlib.Path.cwd().joinpath(output,object['path'])
print(path)
```